# How to retrieve repeating substrings from a string?

Tags: php

how to explode even words in string of symbol "-"? for ex.:

```
$string = 'tshirt-blue-124-tshirt-blue-124-tshirt-blue-124';
```

or

```
$string = '333-red-333-red-333-red-333-red';
```

I need array like this:

```
$string[0] = 'tshirt-blue-124';
$string[1] = 'tshirt-blue-124';
$string[2] = 'tshirt-blue-124';
```

or

```
 $string[0] = '333-red';
 $string[1] = '333-red';
 $string[2] = '333-red';
 $string[3] = '333-red';
```

thanks

Comment: Has the "even word" already been provided or you want to also detect it from the string?

Comment: Should we assume that the string will not always look like that? If so, then *how* should a solution, to this question, know what to look for?

Comment: Could you provide us with more general information? A solution to your example problem is easy, but what are you trying to achieve in general? Do you want to parse batches of three words from a string? What do you mean with "even string words"?

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: explode words of symbol "-" but even words. Of my string even words is tshirt-blue-124 and connected with "-"

Comment: What would you expect `$string = '333-red-333-red-333red-333red';` to be broken down to?

Comment: Please be clear on this: Are the "even words" given as an input?

Comment: I think @HaroldasKerušauskas is trying to get repeating substrings from a string, right?

Comment: yes @jeromegamez exactly

Answer (score 3):

If it's always every three elements:

```
$string = 'tshirt-blue-124-tshirt-blue-124-tshirt-blue-124';

$newArray = array_chunk(explode('-', $string), 3);
array_walk(
    $newArray, 
    function(&$value) {
        $value = implode('-', $value);
});
var_dump($newArray);
```

**EDIT**

But you must know how many elements in advance:

```
$splitValue = 2;
$string = '333-red-333-red-333-red-333-red';

$newArray = array_chunk(explode('-', $string), $splitValue);
array_walk(
    $newArray, 
    function(&$value) {
        $value = implode('-', $value);
});
var_dump($newArray);
```

**EDIT #2**

If you have no idea how many elements that there in a repetition block, then look into the [Lempel-Ziv-Welsh (LZW) compression algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZW). It is built on detecting repetitions in strings and utilizing them for compression. You can probably use a [Suffix Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) datastructure to simplify the logic.

**EDIT #3**

As a simplistic approach to trying to identify the split size:

```
function getSplitSize($string) {
    $splitSize = 2;
    do {
        $tempArray = array_chunk(explode('-', $string), $splitSize);
        if ($tempArray[0] == $tempArray[1])
            return $splitSize;
        ++$splitSize;
    } while ($splitSize <= count($tempArray));
    throw new Exception('No repetition found');
}

function splitStringOnRepetition($string) {
    $newArray = array_chunk(explode('-', $string), getSplitSize($string));
    array_walk(
        $newArray, 
        function(&$value) {
            $value = implode('-', $value);
        }
    );
    return $newArray;
}


$string = 'tshirt-blue-124-tshirt-blue-124-tshirt-blue-124';
$array = splitStringOnRepetition($string);
var_dump($array);

$string = '333-red-333-red-333-red-333-red';
$array = splitStringOnRepetition($string);
var_dump($array);
```

Comment: i edited my question. in string can by 4 or 5 or etc. elements.

Comment: but if i dont know how many element are in the string with even sentence?

Comment: If you don't know how many elements make up a block, is it always an exact duplication of values? ie __not__ `$string = 'tshirt-blue-124-tshirt-blue-125-tshirt-blue-126';`

Comment: yes always will be exact duplication

Answer (score 1):

For advanced yet efficient method, you can use a regular expression matching using `preg_match()`:

```
$string = 'tshirt-blue-124-tshirt-blue-125-tshirt-blue-126';
$pattern = "/([A-Za-z]*-[A-Za-z]*-[\d]*)-?/";
preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($matches[1]);
echo "</pre>";
```

and it will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => tshirt-blue-124
    [1] => tshirt-blue-125
    [2] => tshirt-blue-126
)
```

you can set the pattern the way you want..

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
$string = 'tshirt-blue-124-tshirt-blue-124-tshirt-blue-124';
$tmp = explode("-", $string);
while ($tmp) {
               $output[] = implode('-', array_splice($tmp, 0, 3));
              }
print_r($output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with -

```
$string = 'tshirt-blue-124-tshirt-blue-124-tshirt-blue-124';

$new = explode('-', $string);
$i = 0;
$result = array();
while ($i < count($new)) {
   $result[] = $new[$i].'-'.$new[$i+1].'-'.$new[$i+2];
   $i += 3;
}
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Explode it

```
$string = explode("tshirt-", $string);
```

Now you have to add the value to each Array element

```
foreach($string as &$v){
    $v = "tshirt-" . $v;
    $v = rtrim($v, "-");
}
```

This is a very easy and simple to understand solution.